# 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime') or 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.getTime')

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS 1.0.3 and PhantomJS 1.9.0. Every now and then, an error comes up saying `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime') [object Object],[object Object]`. Even more rarely, it will be `b.getTime` instead of `c.startedAt.getTime`. It only happens on a few select pages, and the only thing that these pages have in common is that they are very JavaScript-heavy.

The pages are loading and behaving exactly as expected when this error happens, and the test continues to run exactly as it should, but this error is causing a lot of false negatives from a pure pass/fail perspective.

I've evaluated all of the javascript that is used on the pages this error surfaces, and `c.startedAt.getTime` and `b.getTime` are not in any of the files, both in dev and minified versions.

Has anyone ever seen this error? Is it an issue with CasperJS? PhantomJS? The fact that it only happens on a few specific pages makes me think it's a problem with those pages, but like I said, I can't find anything that even remotely resembles `c.startedAt.getTime` or `b.getTime` in the source javascript.

I've also used CasperJS 1.0.2 and PhantomJS 1.9.1 in various combinations, and have still gotten the errors.

Logs for a bit of context:

```
[info] [phantom] Step 1143/1151: done in 18ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 1144/1151 (url removed for privacy)
[info] [phantom] Step 1144/1151: done in 0ms.
FAIL Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime') [object Object],[object Object]
Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object   (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime')[object Object],[object Object]
[Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime')[object Object],[object Object]] fail failed
[Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.startedAt.getTime')[object Object],[object Object]] subject: false
 #    type: fail
 #    subject: false
```

Comment: Most JavaScript libraries lack internal error checking for performance reasons. Thus, improper invocations of library services often cause errors inside the library. The root problem, however, is not the library code itself, but something built on it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because you are not waiting for the object to load. Either use `waitForSelector` if its a specific div or use `wait`. Just do a quick test by using

```
casper.wait(11000, function(){
    //your code here
});
```

You may need to replace `casper` with whichever object is requiring `casper`.